# How to exit aspx page by gridview selectedindex changed event and selected session update in another window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textboxes and dropdowns in a form .. Am searching a person details from another form am giving sessions to fields.. After getting the sessions i have to close search form in my main form fields to be affected.. Am trying to close search form but am getting postback error.. My code is like this..

**Serach Form**(Contains Grid)

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid_search_res" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="PMRN" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_search_res_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCreated="grid_search_res_RowCreated">
<Columns>
<asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="fa fa-search" Text="Select" HeaderText="Select" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PMRN" HeaderText="PMRN" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Adress" HeaderText="Address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code**

```
 protected void grid_search_res_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    grow = grid_search_res.SelectedRow;
    Pmrn = grid_search_res.DataKeys[grow.RowIndex].ToString();

    DataTable dt = getado.retrievedata("Exec S_POP_PatientDetails 2 , '" +Pmrn + "' , 0 , 100 , 1");
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    Session["pmrn"] = dt.Rows[0]["PMRN"].ToString();
    }
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
 }
```

**Main Form**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_PMRN" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

**I Want this txt_PMRN to be fill with the session PMRN
When am exiting the search form**

Please Help Me

Thank you

Comment: how do you expect to hold the session variable if you are calling the javascript `window.close()` just use the `Redirect()`